# Microsoft Cognitive Serivces Bing News API how to search multiple languages in 1 query

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am attempting to use the V5 Bing News API. On the documentation here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760793.aspx#news) it shows that for multiple language searches, you would specify the Accept-Language in the header, and the cc field in the query.

So for example if I want both French and English results, from both US and France, I did:

`Accept-Language: fr,en
cc=FR,US`

But this is not working. This only returns US/English results. If I remove the US/English portion, I would get french results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get results from one language per API call. If you want to get results for multiple languages for the query, then you need to call the API twice passing the appropriate headers/params to customize the language.